# How do I test whether an app is vulnerable to the sprockets vulnerability?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, sprockets

What web request should I run to test if a Rails application is vulnerable to the sprockets vulnerability CVE-2018-3760?

I've made the necessary changes that ought to make it safe from that issue, but I'd like to test it out by seeing what happens both on a secure version and a non-secure version

I tried `http://localhost:3000/assets/file:%2f%2f///Users/agrimm/rails/sprockets_replication/README.rdoc` on an example Rails application running in production mode on a development machine using Google Chrome, but it didn't retrieve the file even with an insecure version of sprockets and with `config.assets.compile = true` in `production.rb`. (I wouldn't be surprised if the path of the web request is wrong - it's a bit of a wild guess)

Neither https://blog.heroku.com/rails-asset-pipeline-vulnerability nor https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-security/ft_J--l55fM gave examples of how to test for the vulnerability.

Comment: Do you have `config.assets.compile = true`? The [patch](https://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-security/attach/7740e7d03baee/4-0-fix-path-traversal.patch?part=0.3&authuser=0&view=1) includes `get "assets/file:%2f%2f//#{absolute_path}/foo.js"` in the tests so it looks like you're on the right track with that URL.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, thanks for asking, and added to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remember that this works with assets so trying with a file that is outside of the assets folder like

```
/path/to/project/folder/app/assets/config 
/path/to/project/folder/app/assets/images 
/path/to/project/folder/app/assets/javascripts 
/path/to/project/folder/app/assets/stylesheets 
/path/to/project/folder/vendor/assets/javascripts 
/path/to/project/folder/vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

or all the assets folder gems wouldn't work.

so the one you are trying wouldn't work because it will throw an error of `Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths`, it even recognizes that the file exist, because if you see on the log, there is a

```
Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths (/path/to/project/folder/README.md is no longer under a load path)
```

and if it doesn't exist, you will see an error of

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound (could not find file)
```

so you are on the right path, but needs to try with an asset file on those folders listed, something like:

```
localhost:3000/assets/file:%2f%2f///path/to/project/folder/app/assets/stylesheets/devise.css
```

with this you will see an asset being returned by the browser.

And after updating the gem sprockets to 3.7.2, with `config.assets.compile = true` and try to access again to the same address, you will see a page that just says `forbidden` and nothing else.

those where my conclusions on the tests that I did on local, and with those instructions you can test the vulnerability that is the objective of the question

Comment: Thanks. It looks like another factor in my problem was that I was using a (very) old version of Rails, which for some reason didn't seem to be affected. The replication I had created also used an old version of Rails. When I created an app with a recent version of Rails, I was able to reproduce the vulnerability.